# Create 5-partition files in Spark(Core using RDD) WordCount program using scala based on 'A', 'E', 'I','O','U' vowels

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Create 5-partition files in Spark(Core using RDD) WordCount program using scala based on `'A', 'E', 'I','O','U'` vowels, i.e 5-files each containing on words of each vowel and count.

For Example, if the file abc.txt has text as below.

```
"Apple America Apple Elephant Egg Engine Image Ink Orange Uniform" the 5-part files should be as below

part-0
Apple, 2
America, 1

part-1
Elephant, 1
Egg, 1
Engine, 1

part-2
Image, 1
Ink, 1

part-3
Orange, 1

part-4
Uniform, 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Gulrez, you can implement a custom `Partitioner` for this. For instance :

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("Apple America Apple Elephant Egg Engine Image Ink Orange Uniform"))

  val partitioner: Partitioner = new Partitioner {
    override def numPartitions: Int = 5
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key.toString.head match {
      case 'A' => 0
      case 'E' => 1
      case 'I' => 2
      case 'O' => 3
      case 'U' => 4
    }
  }

  val partitionedAndReducedRDD = rdd.flatMap(_.split(" "))
      .groupBy({s: String => s}, partitioner)
      .mapValues(_.size)

  partitionedAndReducedRDD.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/output/")
```

Then we get 5 files (1 per partition) with below content :

```
$ cat /tmp/output/part-00000 
(Apple,2)
(America,1)

$ cat /tmp/output/part-00001
(Elephant,1)
(Engine,1)
(Egg,1)

$ cat /tmp/output/part-00002
(Image,1)
(Ink,1)

$ cat /tmp/output/part-00003
(Orange,1)

$ cat /tmp/output/part-00004
(Uniform,1)
```